# Can copy-editing an existing answer create value to justify a new answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

You may have seen answers around the SE network that were technically correct but had "problems" that limited their usefulness. For example:

- Waaay too long and unnecessarily so; few people would have the time and attention to read it.
- Written in a highly technical way; few people would understand it.

If there was a shorter, simpler version, it could make the information useful to a lot more people. That's what copy editors<sup>[1]</sup> do; they rewrite the words to better say the ideas. Could a much-improved copy edit of the answer be posted as a new answer?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *<sub>"Copy" is the publishing industry term for content. While an "edit" can refer to any kind of change, including adding new facts and ideas, "copy editing" generally refers to changes that present the ideas better but don't involve adding new ideas or facts.</sub>*

Answer (score 3):

### Some context

- **Posts are knowledge base contributions.**  SE sites aren't help sites in the usual sense, or a support forum, even though it usually appears that way on the surface. They're a curated knowledge base. There may be some user interaction to clarify and fine-tune posts. But the high-level perspective is that questioners and answerers contribute knowledge base "content", and the questioner may get an answer out of it in the process.

  Submissions of content need to fit the posting structure, guidelines, and intended design and purpose of the knowledge base. As will be discussed, copy edited answers are contrary to pretty much everything an answer is intended and designed to be on the platform.
- **Avoid duplication by design.**  The audience for the content is not the questioner. The vast majority of people who read the content find it in a search. They are the audience the SE network is designed to serve.

  One thing that makes the information valuable is the ability to efficiently find information without needing to wade through duplication and noise. So there is a focus on avoiding and eliminating duplication and noise. The platform defines copy edited answers as duplicates.
- **Reality of complex systems.**  There are always cases where there could be benefit from doing something another way. But you can't design systems like the SE network to handle every edge case in the optimum way. That would be too complex to have a system at all.

  For something like making the information in a few answers more accessible, you need to weigh how much benefit that would bring against the added complexity of working outside the system design, and the community moderation workload it would produce. Every exception comes at a cost.

### The role of editing

The gist of how the platform conceptualizes the issue is this:

- Each answer should contribute ideas and facts that haven't previously been contributed.
- If an existing answer covers the points you want to make, don't post them again as a new answer.
- If you think you can improve on how the existing answer is explained, the prescribed way to do it is by editing the existing answer.
- If you edit the existing answer, that is still considered the same answer.
- What if, instead of making the edits **on** that answer, you post what the edits would look like in a new answer? That's the same answer in another location (a duplicate). The corollary is that any answer that is effectively a copy edit of an existing answer is a duplicate.

The platform does not contemplate copy-edits of answers as new answers, and since they don't contribute new ideas, they are viewed as duplicates with no value. Making the information accessible to more people by posting a different version of it in a new answer isn't something the platform recognizes as appropriate or valuable.

### Attribution and plagiarism considerations

Since the answer is (or is effectively) a rewrite of another answer, the previous answer must be attributed.

The [Help Section guidance on attribution](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) also clarifies that an existing answer should be used only as support for new ideas; an answer should never consist of just a quote of something else (which would also apply to a rewrite of something else). This goes to the point of answers being expected to contribute new ideas, and an answer that contains only things previously covered not being intended as an answer.

This is further addressed in [This FAQ post on plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078/269940) ("copied text" would also apply to rewritten text of someone else's work):

> Remember, you still have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work either.

That raises another aspect. The subject matter content of the answer is considered an example of **your** work, and that's what the reputation earned through voting on the post reflects. The trust people put in your answers is based on the reputation earned for your subject matter expertise, not for your skills as an English editor. Reputation gained through polishing the words on someone else's ideas would be a distortion.

If you were going to post an answer that is just a copy edit of another answer, the appropriate way to do it would be as a community wiki post.

### Community Moderation

Maybe the originators of the network didn't consider the potential value of a good rewrite in special cases. Maybe it's too big of a change for an edit, or the answer author rejects the edit. Are we going to deny people access to the information in a form that's useful to them?

Nothing precludes people posting answers that don't comply with the guidelines (you may have noticed that on occasion). Community moderation sorts it out. Assuming it meets the basic posting requirements and includes attribution, the community can make an exception if it thinks the answer adds substantive value. Value is reflected in upvotes and downvotes, and the community can flag the answer for deletion as a duplicate if it doesn't add value.

### Bottom Line

Posting a rewrite as a new answer is contrary to the platform intentions and guidelines. However, every possible edge case can't be anticipated, so the final decision is vested in the community.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>*There is much historical discussion to be found on MetaSE about similar answers. [This highly valued answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243255/269940) even discusses the value of a better explanation. The distinction in those cases is that they reflect people posting their own thoughts in similar ways. The "better explanation" often comes from a different perspective or approach the person can bring due to subject matter knowledge.*</sub>